# Node app deployed to Azure App Service : Error: The service is unavailable

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I followed a [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/getting-started) on deploying a simple Node app from VSCode using the Azure App Service extension.

The app runs fine locally.

When I deploy I get this output:

```
Creating resource group "appsvc_linux_centralus" in location "centralus"...
Successfully created resource group "appsvc_linux_centralus".
Ensuring App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus" exists...
Creating App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus"...
Successfully created App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus".
Creating new web app "XXX-node-users-api"...
Created new web app "XXX-node-users-api": https://XXX-node-users-api.azurewebsites.net
21:28:12 XXX-node-users-api: Creating zip package...
21:28:33 XXX-node-users-api: Starting deployment...
Error: The service is unavailable.
```

In the portal there is nothing listed in `Diagnose and solve problems`. How can I tell why the service in unavailable (which it does show when I click on the link)?

UPDATE:
I followed the same process with a different Node app (which I got from another [MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs)) and I got this:

```
Using existing resource group "appsvc_linux_centralus".
Ensuring App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus" exists...
Successfully found App Service plan "appsvc_linux_centralus".
Creating new web app "nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805"...
Created new web app "nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805": https://nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805.azurewebsites.net
22:13:06 nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805: Creating zip package...
22:13:07 nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805: Starting deployment...
22:14:31 nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805: Fetching changes.
22:14:31 nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/59khfmlp.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
22:14:31 nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805: Central Directory corrupt.
Error: Deployment to "nodejs-docs-hello-world-20190805" failed. See output channel for more details.
```

I get the feeling I'm doing something obvious wrong or the extension is mangling the code. Where do I start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy my app (the first one I tried to deploy to Azure) to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) which in comparison was simple and the logs trivially easy to get.

Doing this pointed to two changes I needed to make. I could then deploy to Azure using the VS Code extension.

1. There was not a `npm start` script in `package.json` so I added one.
2. The port was being set statically. Which, for Heroku at least, is not allowed. Changed

`var server = app.listen(3000, function () {`

to

`var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {`

Interestingly the second repo I tried already used both of these techniques so I'm no wiser as to how I might address that.